# Angular 1.3 and minimal required JQuery version

Tags: jquery, angularjs

We have a huge system, developed fully with angular, from scratch (no non-angular legacy code, no other non-angular frameworks)

Shame on us, we are still working with angular 1.2.12 (!!) and an old JQuery version (1.8.3)

Recently I was assigned to migrate our system to work with latest stable angular (=1.3.14)

Surprisingly** enough, when briefed on angular's source code, I found the below remark (at the method: `bindJQuery`)

> // Angular 1.3+ technically requires at least jQuery 2.1+ but it may
>   work with older
>
> // versions. It will not work for sure with jQuery <1.7, though.

(Surprisingly** = I could not find it mentioned in the formal migration guide from angular 1.2 to 1.3 nor at angular's change log... have I missed that ?)

As we currently have no plans (in terms of time and effort estimation) to migrate our JQuery version as well, I wanted to ask:

- Does any one knows if there are any actual known bugs and pitfalls
  when trying to force angular 1.3 work with jQuery 1.8.3 ?
- Are there any suspicious areas I should pay more attention in searching
  for errors and strange behavior ?
- Is this something I should avoid from to begin with ?

Thanks a'head

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot change the jquery version you are using, at least for the latest 1.x? Unless you are using very specific methods in a very specific way, I doubt there would be any issue in migrating to a newer 1.x version. I suggest you at least try.

Comment: We are using JQuery 1.8.3. 
The only reason for not updating JQuery is due to the risk that might be involved in changing this fundamental library version and how it might affects our application. 
I guess that if we'll go and upgrade - we are better do the upgrade to the latest JQuery (same as we are upgrading angular to the latest available and not to the latest 1.2.x)

Comment: Angular 1.3 works fine with jquery 1.8. One of our apps is currently using those versions.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Angular's FAQ](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#does-angular-use-the-jquery-library-), Angular 1.3.x supports jQuery 2.1 and above. Here's what is says:

> **Does Angular use the jQuery library?**
>
> Yes, Angular can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped. If jQuery is not present in your script path, Angular falls back to its own implementation of the subset of jQuery that we call [jQLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).
>
> Angular 1.3 only supports jQuery 2.1 or above. jQuery 1.7 and newer might work correctly with Angular but we don't guarantee that.

Yes, this doesn't give you an exact answer on what might be broken. But "might" and "don't guarantee" should give you a strong indication that Angular was not tested with < jQuery 2.1. In my book it is very bad.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I read the FAQ's once when started to work with angular - and never again later on :)
Eventually it's the same remark like in the code - thus my original question remains - how really bad is it ?

Comment: @aviadcohen, I think the following like from the FAQ should give you a hint: "*might* work correctly with Angular but we *don't guarantee that*.". In other words, it hasn't been tested - thus quite bad!